# Installing Ubuntu to a laptop without cd rom

Tags: installation

I am new to Ubuntu. How can I clean Install Ubuntu to a Laptop without a CD Rom and if I put ISO file in a Flashdrive how it works when booting up?

Comment: Do you have an existing OS now?

Comment: I do not have a OS now, so I can not use UNetbootin

Comment: Unfortunately you have to create the USB on a different machine, one that has an OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net). Download it, make sure you have no external USB drives plugged in except the one you want to use for installing Ubuntu, and launch UNetbootin.

[image]

Select Ubuntu, the version of Ubuntu you want (select `12.04_Live` for the long term support version, or `13.04_Live` for the most recent version) and click OK. Then wait until it's done.

You then can boot from that USB drive and then you can try or install Ubuntu!